# Unequal variances but equal means

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval, heteroscedasticity

Assume the sample ${(x_i)}_{i=1}^{n_1} \sim_{\text{iid}} {\cal N}(\mu, \sigma_1^2)$ is independent of the sample ${(y_i)}_{i=1}^{n_2} \sim_{\text{iid}} {\cal N}(\mu, \sigma_2^2)$. What are the available methods to get a confidence interval about the common mean $\mu$ ? In my case I have $n_1=n_2$. I would be satisfied by an answer for this case but I'm also interested in the general case.

Comment: You should answer your own quetion as an answer not only as edit to post, so it is possible to upvote it (so removing from unanswered queue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution in [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037837589900052X): 
*On exact confidence intervals for the common mean of several normal populations* by Philip L.H. Yua, Yijun Sunb, Bimal K. Sinha.

( The same paper with free access: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.50.7844&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

And I found the old code I used to get the CI based on Fisher's inversion method, whose details are given in the paper.

```
# simulate data
set.seed(666)
y1 <- rnorm(100, 5, .1)
y2 <- rnorm(100, 5, .3)
ybar1 <- mean(y1)
ybar2 <- mean(y2)
v1 <- var(y1)
v2 <- var(y2)
n1 <- length(y1)
n2 <- length(y2)

# product of p-values (denoted by P_i in the paper)
f <- function(mu){
  pf(n1*(ybar1-mu)^2/v1, df1=1, df2=n1-1, lower.tail=FALSE)*pf(n2*(ybar2-mu)^2/v2, df1=1, df2=n2-1, lower.tail=FALSE)
}
# the 95%-confidence interval is given by the intersection points 
curve(f(x), from=4.95, to=5.04)
abline(h=exp(-qchisq(0.95,4)/2), col="red")
```

[image]

```
# bounds of the confidence interval
g <- function(mu) f(mu)-exp(-qchisq(0.95,4)/2)
uniroot(g, c(4.94, 4.98))$root
[1] 4.966296
uniroot(g, c(5, 5.06))$root
[1] 5.014669
```

### EDIT

Another method, actually a *generalized confidence interval* is given in [Iyer & Patterson, "A recipe for constructing generalized pivotal quantities and generalized confidence intervals](http://quantum.stat.colostate.edu/statresearch/stattechreports/Technical%20Reports/2002/02_10.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for combining them using the [inverse variance method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-variance_weighting) to weight each measure prior to getting a common variance?

Comment: See my edit for the link. I have adopted Fisher's method. Very easy actually !

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent: Unfortunately the link is behind a paywall, but I noticed a later paper that addressed the Behrens–Fisher problem which makes it interesting theoretically. Wondering what
Fisher method they/you are referring to?

Comment: @phaneron ?? The link works well for me.

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent: The paywall is letting you through but not me.

Comment: @phaneron Ok. So type the title of the paper in Google and will find it for free.

Comment: Useful recommendation, and what I would have done as well. What about the formula for the standard error of the inverse variance weighted mean?